# scaling websocket game application server

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, lua

I'm developing a realtime multi-player game with websocket (Python3 + autobahn)

The game will be played in rooms. Players in a single room should be grouped together to allow messaging, game play, etc. So it's more or less like a chat server.

I'm having a hard time scaling this to a multi server scenario. I did some searching but wasn't happy with the result I've found.

One way I came up with was with nginx + lua.

So the idea is that when a player join a particular room, it'll send the room id in the message. With nginx + lua I plan to decide which of the app server instances it should go to. The result is that all players in the same room will eventually end up in the same instance.

A few questions:

1. Can nginx + lua intercept the websocket message and then pass the connection?
2. This will involve hard-coding logic in the reverse proxy layer. And the backend connection will be hard-coded also. Is there a way to make them dynamic?

Any suggestion to whether this is good idea or not is appreciated as well suggestions for better design.

Answer (score 0):

If the room ID is in the URL you can use openresty to parse it and then change the proxy_pass target to the desired backend. 
To do this you would define a variable in nginx, then set it in access_by_lua, and finally proxy pass to the new variable.

You can make the lookup dynamic by storing the room ID -> backend server address mapping in your favourite database and reading it with openresty, and even use openresty's shared dicts to cache the mapping so it doesn't hammer the DB.

So in the location block of your nginx.conf you would have something like:

```
set $target '';
access_by_lua '
  --[[
    - parse the url/headers
    - lookup the room ID in the database
  --]]

  ngx.var.target = host
'; 
proxy_pass http://$target;
```

Another option depending on your game would be to move some of the logic itself to openresty since it can handle the websockets directly.